# Adding labels to D3 generated circles

Tags: d3.js, label

I just started learning `d3`, and very first thing I made is [this sorta lame fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2MhZq/2/)

Now I wonder how should I attach labels to those circles. Is it possible to nest a label (let's say current radius value) in a circle so it would always move with the circle, or you have to treat labels like independent objects and manage everything accordingly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a grouping element (`<g>`) to hold both the circle and the associated text label so they are always together.  Then you can position the enter group by using the `translate` command on the `transform` attribute (instead of positioning the circle directly as you're doing now).

So basically, you bind the data to the `<g>` elements instead of to the `<circle>` elements as you're doing now.  Then you can just append a "circle" and a "text" to the "g" (no data join) and both of those child elements will automatically inherit the data themselves.